# Can I use 'that' for plural nouns?

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

> The amount of white collar job openings in Bangladesh on average is
> not enough to satiate the needs of the thousands of graduates **that**
> want jobs.

> The amount of white collar job openings in Bangladesh on average is
> not enough to satiate the needs of the thousands of graduates **who**
> want jobs.

Are the above sentences correct? Can I use who and that for plural nouns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are talking about people, ***who*** is more polite, and idiomatic, than ***that***.

If you are talking about objects - such as cars or houses - then ***that*** is the one to use.

Comment: While **who** is correct and conventional, **that** is also possible after a person or people. For example, it's acceptable to write:  **The pirates that roamed the Atlantic / the gunman that opened fire, / the soldiers that I saw**

Comment: @RonaldSole Yes, I do not disagree with that.